# Connecting Two Iterators In ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

I created a model for iterate with feature dataset and feature class but problem is iterate dataset iterating all datasets but passing last dataset to iterate feature class.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Iterate dataset as a sub model but we need use as main remaing will sub model[image]

Main Model
[image]

SubModel

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or is it intended to clarify your question?  If it's the latter then it should be an edit to it.

Comment: yes that is the answer

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, each iterator must be in its own separate model.  So place your "Iterate Feature" iterator in its own model, then create a *third* model in which the two iterator models are connected.  Think of the third model as the main model, and the iterator models as submodels.

Comment: Created Three models.now its running on single feature class

Comment: So, is your problem solved?

Comment: NO. after creating three Models  its looping all datasets and passing last dataset to iterate to feature class ,and its looping through feature classes inside dataset and   passing last feature class only for clip tool.tool and execution is stopped.